# import functions from created template from material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use the templates available in the material-ui website into my project since it works fine for a short amount of work time. I want to create a login system which has a user login and it redirects the user to their dashboard. i had found the templates of both of these components from material-ui and have saved them as separate .js files. I am new to reactjs, hence, do not know much about it's working but here is an option to import the functions from other .js files as far as I saw on some tutorials. But in my case the function doesn't import even though I clearly state the imports.

code for signin page

```
import React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
//import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
//import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';
//import DashboardContent from './DashBoardFaculty';
import Dashboard from './DashBoardFaculty';
//import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const theme = createTheme();

export default function SignIn() {
    const [username, setusername]= useState("");
    const [password, setpassword]= useState("");
    const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log({
      facultyName: username,
      password: password,
    });
  };

  const login = () => {

    //let navigate = useNavigate(); 
      Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
          username: username,
          password: password,
        }).then((response) => {
          if(response.data.message) {
            setLoginStatus(response.data.message)
          }
    
        });
    };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <Box
          sx={{
            marginTop: 8,
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
            <LockOutlinedIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Sign in
          </Typography>
          <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
            <TextField
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="username"
              label="Faculty Name"
              name="Faculty Name"
              autoComplete="name"
              autoFocus
              onChange={(e)=>setusername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <TextField
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              name="password"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              id="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
              onChange={(e)=>setpassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
              label="Remember me"
            />
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
              onClick={login}
            >
              Sign In
            </Button>
            <h4>{loginStatus}</h4>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

code for dashboard

```
 import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
//import List from '@mui/material/List';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Badge from '@mui/material/Badge';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import NotificationsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Notifications';
//import { mainListItems, secondaryListItems } from './listItems';
//import Chart from './Chart';
//import Deposits from './Deposits';
//import Orders from './Orders';

function Copyright(props) {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary" align="center" {...props}>
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://mui.com/">
        Your Website
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const drawerWidth = 240;

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
      position: 'relative',
      whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
      width: drawerWidth,
      transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
      }),
      boxSizing: 'border-box',
      ...(!open && {
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
        width: theme.spacing(7),
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
          width: theme.spacing(9),
        },
      }),
    },
  }),
);

const mdTheme = createTheme();

function DashboardContent() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={mdTheme}>
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar position="absolute" open={open}>
          <Toolbar
            sx={{
              pr: '24px', // keep right padding when drawer closed
            }}
          >
            <IconButton
              edge="start"
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="open drawer"
              onClick={toggleDrawer}
              sx={{
                marginRight: '36px',
                ...(open && { display: 'none' }),
              }}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography
              component="h1"
              variant="h6"
              color="inherit"
              noWrap
              sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
            >
              Faculty Dashboard
            </Typography>
            <IconButton color="inherit">
              <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
                <NotificationsIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
          <Toolbar
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'flex-end',
              px: [1],
            }}
          >
            <IconButton onClick={toggleDrawer}>
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
          <Divider />
        </Drawer>
        <Box
          component="main"
          sx={{
            backgroundColor: (theme) =>
              theme.palette.mode === 'light'
                ? theme.palette.grey[100]
                : theme.palette.grey[900],
            flexGrow: 1,
            height: '100vh',
            overflow: 'auto',
          }}
        >
          <Toolbar />
          <Container maxWidth="lg" sx={{ mt: 4, mb: 4 }}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
              {/* Chart */}
              <Grid item xs={12} md={8} lg={9}>
                <Paper
                  sx={{
                    p: 2,
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    height: 240,
                  }}
                >
                </Paper>
              </Grid>
              {/* Recent Deposits */}
              <Grid item xs={12} md={4} lg={3}>
                <Paper
                  sx={{
                    p: 2,
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    height: 240,
                  }}
                >
                </Paper>
              </Grid>
              {/* Recent Orders */}
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Paper sx={{ p: 2, display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                </Paper>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Copyright sx={{ pt: 4 }} />
          </Container>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default function Dashboard() {
  return <DashboardContent />;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So at the end, which of the imports are not working then?

Answer (score 0):

I think the imports he is talking about that are not working are those in the dashboard code, the line that are commented in grey.
I suppose that he installed Material UI and copy that template, but some of the imports that are needed there aren't in the installation doc. You have to install them by your own.

```js
// import { mainListItems, secondaryListItems } from './listItems';
// import Chart from './Chart';
// import Deposits from './Deposits';
// import Orders from './Orders';
```

But where and how find those lib? If anyone has an answer, I have the same problem too.